# UIToolBar button flicker

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar with a few UIBarButtons - it is embedded into a handful of views. The buttons can be enabled/disabled as needed. The problem is that every time I switch to a new view, the disabled buttons light up for a fraction of a second before resuming their disabled state. I have tried initializing the buttons in a disabled state from the storyboard, and moving the code from `viewDidLoad` in the toolbar view controller. No luck. I have been stuck at this point for a few days...Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

For testing purposes, I’ve been using the following code in `ToolBarViewController.swift` where notesButton is an `IBOutlet` of type `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    notesButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

As you can see, when I change views by pressing a button, the setting button will go to full opacity for a brief second before resuming its disabled appearance:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code where you are disabling the button?

Comment: what do you mean by "buttons light up for a fraction of a second" if you are talking about color. Than I don't see where you are changing the color. As far I know by making isEnable = false/true will only affect the User Intraction not appearnce. Do you want to hide/show button then use isHiden = true/false, Also you can upload the image of gif so we get more clear picture about the question

Comment: I have added a photo - as you can see, simply disabling the button causes its opacity to be reduced by about half.

Comment: notesButton.image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image with rendering mode original, so it will always stick to original and not change base on the button state.

```
notesButton.image = UIImage(named: "YourImageName")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
```

**PS:** I haven't tested this you can try and let me know if it works or can check UIToolBar tint colour or button colour to white so it will always stay white.

Comment: So, that does keep the button white - which does take care of the flicker, but I would still like disabled buttons to have the dimmed appearance. I'll keep trying. Maybe there's something in the rendering mode that will help. Thank you.

Comment: You can use two images or if you can show how flicker is happening and when exactly, than can help better, Anyway you can still keep the rendering mode template, but set the image in view didLoad so it will not look like flicker or can also do it in slow animation